# How to cut date and time

Tags: r, time, posixct

i have time series data with 3 variables, Time Date and price..
then i used as.POSIXct function to combine date and time into 1 columns and formatted it,
then i want to cut my data by date and time example from "2018-03-05  09:00:00" to "2018-03-05  14:15:00 "

I want to cut data with date and time, 
this is my real data

```
df1
Date         time       price
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:30    125.9
2018-03-05  11:03:00    125.9
2018-03-05  12:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  15:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  14:15:00    125.9
2018-03-05  17:00:01    125.9
```

and im using `as.POSIXct` function to combine time and date and  my data like this

```
        Date             Price
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:30    125.9
2018-03-05  11:03:00    125.9
2018-03-05  12:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  15:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  14:15:00    125.9
2018-03-05  17:00:01    125.9
```

where is from 3 variables, become two variable.

then am using

```
df1[df1$Date<=as.Date('2018-03-05'),];
```

then ..it doesnt work

and i want my results like this, where cut by date from "2018-03-05  09:00:00" to "2018-03-05  14:15:00 "

```
   Date             Price
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:30    125.9
2018-03-05  11:03:00    125.9
2018-03-05  12:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  15:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  14:15:00    125.9
```

Answer (score 0):

You can tranform your strings with `as.POSIXct` for date and time comparisons.

```
subset(df1,
       Date >= as.POSIXct("2018-03-05 09:00:00") & Date <= as.POSIXct("2018-03-05 14:15:00"))
```

The result:

```
                 Date Price
1 2018-03-05 09:00:00 125.9
2 2018-03-05 09:00:00 125.9
3 2018-03-05 09:00:00 125.9
4 2018-03-05 10:00:01 125.9
5 2018-03-05 10:00:30 125.9
6 2018-03-05 11:03:00 125.9
7 2018-03-05 12:00:01 125.9
9 2018-03-05 14:15:00 125.9
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(tidyverse) # includes dplyr, tidyr
library(lubridate)
```

### Unite Date and time

First, `tidyr::unite()` can paste two columns.

- `col = Date`: name of the new column
- `sep = " "`: works as in `paste()`

Next, `lubridate::ymd_hms()` changes a character to `POSIXct` object of `year-month-day-hour-minute-second` format.

```
(mydf2 <-
  mydf %>% # your data set
  unite(Date, time, col = Date, sep = " ") %>% 
  mutate(Date = ymd_hms(Date)))
#> # A tibble: 10 x 2
#>    Date                price
#>    <dttm>              <dbl>
#>  1 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#>  2 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#>  3 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#>  4 2018-03-05 10:00:01  126.
#>  5 2018-03-05 10:00:30  126.
#>  6 2018-03-05 11:03:00  126.
#>  7 2018-03-05 12:00:01  126.
#>  8 2018-03-05 15:00:00  126.
#>  9 2018-03-05 14:15:00  126.
#> 10 2018-03-05 17:00:01  126.
```

### Cut dates

Using `dplyr::filter()`, you can easily subset the rows.

```
mydf2 %>% 
  filter(Date >= ymd_hms("2018-03-05 09:00:00"), # from 2018-03-05 09:00:00
         Date <= ymd_hms("2018-03-05 14:15:00")) # to 2018-03-05 14:15:00
#> # A tibble: 8 x 2
#>   Date                price
#>   <dttm>              <dbl>
#> 1 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#> 2 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#> 3 2018-03-05 09:00:00  126.
#> 4 2018-03-05 10:00:01  126.
#> 5 2018-03-05 10:00:30  126.
#> 6 2018-03-05 11:03:00  126.
#> 7 2018-03-05 12:00:01  126.
#> 8 2018-03-05 14:15:00  126.
```

---

#### Appendix: importing the data set

```
mydf <-
  read_table("Date         time       price
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  09:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  10:00:30    125.9
2018-03-05  11:03:00    125.9
2018-03-05  12:00:01    125.9
2018-03-05  15:00:00    125.9
2018-03-05  14:15:00    125.9
2018-03-05  17:00:01    125.9")
#------------------------------
mydf
#> # A tibble: 10 x 3
#>    Date       time   price
#>    <date>     <time> <dbl>
#>  1 2018-03-05 09:00   126.
#>  2 2018-03-05 09:00   126.
#>  3 2018-03-05 09:00   126.
#>  4 2018-03-05 10:00   126.
#>  5 2018-03-05 10:00   126.
#>  6 2018-03-05 11:03   126.
#>  7 2018-03-05 12:00   126.
#>  8 2018-03-05 15:00   126.
#>  9 2018-03-05 14:15   126.
#> 10 2018-03-05 17:00   126.
```